# Bring back missing input type date clear field button (Chromium)

Tags: html, google-chrome, microsoft-edge, chromium

When using  `<input type="date">` there used to be a clear (x) button to reset the values once you set it but looks like Chromium removed it in the new form control UI design and you now have to delete every value (mm,dd,yyyy) separate

This is how it looks in the new UI:

[image: This is how it looks in Chromium 81]

This is how it looked in the old one:

[image: This is how it looked till Chromium 81]

Is there a way to bring back the clear button?

(If you are on Google Chrome Stable and would like to see the new UI in action you can enable it under flags here: chrome://flags/#form-controls-refresh )

Comment: I don't think you can bring it back, right now it is only on beta version (Chromium, for example), but read more info here: https://blogs.windows.com/msedgedev/2019/10/15/form-controls-microsoft-edge-chromium/

Answer (score 0):

I'm agree with Calvin's opinion. The new UI without clear button is a trend. And from the article he providing, the new Chromium based Edge deletes the clear button to provide a better touch input experience:

> Our research found that with the large surface area of the fingertip, small controls that are too close together can be difficult to target precisely.

I think it is by design and will be a little difference in different browsers so you can't change it in Microsoft Edge Chromium.